How to display mysql table (data) on kibana in table format
I need to visualize MySQL data for reporting from production servers in Kibana. Is it possible to display MySQL data in a table format on Kibana?
If so, could you please explain how to do it?
I installed ELK and Beats, configured them, and confirmed they're working correctly. I just have one question: Is it possible to display MySQL data in a table format on Kibana?

You can achieve this with the help of tools like Logstash to fetch the data from MySql and pass this to ElasticSearch. Once ElasticSearch receive this data you can use Kibana to visualize it and display the same in table format as per your need.
